# Can the Yongnuo YN622C & YN622C TX be used with the Alien Bees B800?

Tags: strobes, yongnuo

Can the Yongnuo YN622C TX be used with the YN622C controlling the B800 like the Radio Poppers and Pocket Wizards?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "controlling."

If by "controlling" you mean firing in sync, as manual triggers, no sweat. The YN-622C has a PC sync port that you can use to hook it up to an AB800 as a radio receiver, and the Bee will fire in sync.

If by "controlling" you mean firing in sync and letting you remotely set the power level on the AB800, then no. The YN-622C/662C-TX combination only controls the power on Canon eTTL-compatible flashes and requires that the flash have all the pins on a Canon flash foot. The AB800 is a manual studio strobe that doesn't do eTTL and has no flash foot, let alone one that's compatible with the Canon signaling protocol. A PC sync connection is always manual-only.

The PocketWizard AC9 adapter and the RadioPopper capability for controlling an AB power level is doing something different. I think (could be wrong) that they're taking advantage of the built-in power control that the AlienBees have for the Buff [CyberCommander](http://www.paulcbuff.com/cc.php) triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use Yongnuo YN622C II on Alien Bees with a Pocket Wizard AC9 to set the power... It seems to work... :-) even if it's just a short house test and the Alien Bee makes some strange sounds...

Answer (score 0):

Well 1st off yes you can use the YN622C 11 with the Alien Bees but you have to manually change power setting not able to do it by way of remote

Comment: Your answer isn't very clear. Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you use the YN622C TX on camera and the YN622C on the YN flash you can control the flash with the TX, but when you use the YN622C with the b800 and the YN622C TX, you have to manually change the power output by hand not the TX